# in background image url I have got [site_url] instead of real url in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image

I used add_theme_option('custom-background') in my wordpress functions.php file. And it is working but when i set background image i have not got the image. In the page style it is showing [site_url] in the url. But i need to show localhost/wordpress instead of [site_url].The style line is given below:

background-image: url("http://[site_url]/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/pexels-photo-958168.jpeg");

Comment: Is the image you're trying to get on the same domain as the one you want to display it on? You don't need the URL, just '/wp-content/uploads....etc'.

Comment: @SamJohnson yes i tested and it was getting the image but the url is generated automatically.

Comment: You can not use [site_url] like this in your CSS. That will certainly not work.

Comment: @zipkundan I am not using [site_url]. I just used add_theme_option('custom-background'). For this custom-background it generate a inline css and that is background-image: url("http://[site_url]/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/pexels-photo-958168.jpeg") but i need background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/pexels-photo-958168.jpeg")

Comment: You can try using `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` in your php file like this: `<div class="myClass" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/yourimagefolder/imagename.jpg');"></div>`

Comment: @EmmaDalby then it will be static because when i will change my background image from admin panel it will not be changed. Each time i have to change the image from header.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an alternative solutions. The problem is with the theme. Other theme is working correctly. For this theme i did this:

```
<body <?php body_class();?> style="background-image: url('<?php echo substr(get_background_image(),11);?>')">
```

Now it is returning- "wp-content/uploads/2019/02/bg.jpeg". And i will get background image dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `add_theme_support()`, not `add_theme_option()`.

Don't know why it's happening, but a workaround would be to tweak @Emma's suggestion a bit. Something like

```
<?php $url = parse_url(get_background_image(), PHP_URL_PATH); ?>
<div 
    class="myClass" 
    style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url?>)">
</div>
```

(Probably also need to test if the initial image URL is empty or not.)
(And of course this assumes the WordPress install is at the site root. Some further changes might be needed otherwise, and it might end being more like Emma's. I might also add that you could instead use jquery on the client side the fix the problematic URL.)

Comment: I fixed some small errors in one line of the example. Of course, there could be other things going on, e.g., different php versions.